# Wrong Maven Exception

Tags: eclipse, maven, struts2, pom.xml

I am trying to make a new project in eclipse using Maven.
And I used simple "struts-archetype-blank" template of struts.
There is no spring dependencies in it. Still I am getting missing spring artifact error.

Is there any way to resolve the same? Or I am doing something wrong?

[image]

Here is an information pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.krb</groupId>
<artifactId>MySamaj</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>MySamaj</name>

<properties>
    <struts2.version>2.5.5</struts2.version>
    <log4j2.version>1.2.15</log4j2.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
            <configuration>
                <stopKey>CTRL+C</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8999</stopPort>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>xwork.loggerFactory</name>
                        <value>com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.log4j2.Log4j2LoggerFactory</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Did you update a project build path?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`struts2-junit-plugin`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.struts%7Cstruts2-junit-plugin%7C2.5.5%7Cjar) which has transitive dependencies to Spring. Those dependencies are also available from the central Maven repository. For example [`spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-beans%7C4.1.6.RELEASE%7Cjar)

Why the resolving of dependencies is not working cannot be seen in your question. It could be everything from misconfiguration (e.g. settings.xml, private repository, authentication) to network problems (e.g. private repository not reachable).

Answer (score 0):

Your log4j2 version is also wrong. All log4j2 versions start with 2.the current version is 2.8.